# Execute ssh in golang

Tags: go, ssh

I'm looking for a way to launch ssh in a terminal from a golang program.

```golang
func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("ssh", "user@192.168.0.17", "-p", "2222")
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
            panic(err)
    }
}
```

This works great until I enter the correct password, then the program exits. I guess when authentified, another ssh script in launched, but I can't figure out how to solve this. I have searched some infos about it but all I found is how to create a ssh session in go, and I would like to avoid this, if possible.

Comment: So you don't want to use `golang.org/x/crypto/ssh`?

Comment: Exact, I'd like to avoid creating a session inside my program. I just want to launch it as if I launched it from my terminal.

Comment: I just noticed a little issue in your code. You can not just pass all the arguments in one variable. You need to do something like this `exec.Command("ssh", "user@192.168.0.17", "-p" ,"2222")`

Comment: You are right ! I will edit my post, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found another way to solve my issue, by using :

```golang
binary, lookErr := exec.LookPath("ssh")
if lookErr != nil {
    panic(lookErr)
}
syscall.Exec(binary, []string{"ssh", "user@192.168.0.17", "-p", "2222"}, os.Environ())
```

This will close the program's process and launch ssh on another one.
Thanks for helping me !

Answer (score 6):

You should pass in `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("ssh", "user@192.168.0.17", "-p", "2222")
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```